# How do I include a sub blade inside another blade in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Given that I create a blade using the following:

```
View::make('home', $data);
```

And within `home.blade.php` I have the following:

```
@extends('master')
@section('main')
    // groovy content
@stop
```

Where 'master.blade.php' is simply the main wrappers and a `@yield` to 'main'.

If I add `@include` inside `home.blade.php` it no longer extends from `master`.

So how do I include a subblade inside a blade that is extending another.

```
@extends('master')
@section('main')
    // groovy content
    @include('subcontent')
@stop
```

Comment: You can try this, `return View::make('main')->nest('child','home');` where `main.blade.php` extends `master` and `home.blade.php` is the sub-blade which doesn't extends any. In your `main.blade.php` check if child is set or not like `<?php if(isset($child)) echo $child; ?>`

Comment: Are you sure that you can't use `@include` inside your view because it extends a layout ? I think that the code you show is the good one (just verify that the subcontent view doesn't have a `@section`statement).

Comment: I'm pretty sure. When I add the include, everything from the extend isn't rendered/included

Comment: Also, the subcontent must not contain a @stop statement.

Comment: Hmm the subcontent doesn't contain any stop statements, or section statements. Only a foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subchild contained `blade` errors. It wasn't malformed HTML, but rather a php error occurring within an escaped section of the blade. The errors weren't being displayed though (possible because it was nested), so the output of the errors was being suppressed.